# Почему из-за GradientFill программа не компилируется?

Tags: c++, winapi, градиент

Когда я компилирую такой примитивный код, который просто рисует градиент, компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> неразрешённых внешних элементов: 1 
> ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ __imp_GradientFill

Насколько я понял, он пытается вызвать несуществующую функцию __imp_GradientFill.

Код:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    TRIVERTEX vrts[2];
    vrts[0].x = 0;
    vrts[0].y = 0;
    vrts[0].Red = 0x8000;
    vrts[0].Green = 0;
    vrts[0].Blue = 0;

    vrts[1].x = 100;
    vrts[0].y = 100;
    vrts[1].Red = 0x8000;
    vrts[1].Green = 0;
    vrts[1].Blue = 0;

    GRADIENT_RECT rct;
    rct.UpperLeft = 0;
    rct.LowerRight = 1;

    HWND wnd;
    HDC dc;
    wnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    dc = GetDC(wnd);

    GradientFill(dc, vrts, 2, &rct, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_H);

    ReleaseDC(wnd, dc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну не знаю, какой унтерменш посчитал этот вопрос дубликатом совершенно другого вопроса, но, как я понял, задавать вопросы про WinAPI нынче не в моде

Comment: ¿Почему же совершенно другого? Там вопрос про именно эту проблему - "ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ"

Comment: Вы, вероятно, должны обратить внимание на пункт `Используются сторонние библиотеки` этого так называемого «совершенно другого вопроса», а так же на [требования](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gradientfill#requirements) для вашей функции.